# Can't call method "id" on an undefined value

Tags: perl, session

recently my hosting company updated their servers, and i believe my code's inefficiency is being brought to light.

i have this code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use CGI qw(:standard);
    use CGI::Session;

    $cgi = new CGI;

    $sid = $cgi->cookie("CGISESSID") || undef;
    $session = new CGI::Session(undef, $sid, {Directory=>'/tmp'});
    $cookie = $cgi->cookie(CGISESSID => $session->id);
    $sSid = $session->id();

    print $cgi->header(-cookie=>$cookie);

    print  << "EOF";
    HTML CODE
    EOF
```

this was fine until (it seems) the update - now i'm getting this error in my logs:

- Can't call method "id" on an undefined value at /home/users/web/XXXX/my-file.cgi line 10.

i then edited this into line 10:

```
    $cookie = $cgi->cookie(CGISESSID => $session->id) || undef;
```

figuring that it would take care of the issue, but it didn't.

it seems to be causing a brief 500 server error, and then the site comes back online, with the session id persisting through the error.

i'm completely lost as to what is happening. what's worse is it isn't happening every time the page loads - it seems so random but i'm sure i'm just not encountering the specific situation to bring that error.

i've been using the same setup for all my cgi's for the past 7 years. not sure why it's causing a brief error now, but that's besides the point.

Comment: Try printing the output of $sid prior to using it to grab the session to make sure the cookie is being set, if the cookie is good check to see if you really have permission to create files to /tmp if you can't check change the path to some path you have access to with the proper chmod, check to see if your session returns any errors as proposed by ikegami and update your question with your findings.

Answer (score 1):

`$session` is `undef`, so that means `new` returned undef. The docs have the following to say about that:

> Returns new session object, or undef on failure. Error message is accessible through errstr() - class method.

So call `CGI::Session->errstr` to find out what the problem is.